# A relationship's relationship

Tags: apex, soql

I have a custom entity which has a custom relationship 'User' back to the User table.
I can do

```
SELECT Id, User__r.Id from MyCustomEntity
```

However, I want to get a information about the user's manager.

I try:

```
SELECT Id, User__R.Manager__R.email from MyCustomEntity
```

But I get:

```
Save error: Didn't understand relationship 'Manager__R' in field path
```

Is it possible to achieve want I want in SOQL or must I do this in memory programmatically via a separate statement?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Manager is a standard field. It should just be:

```
SELECT Id, User__r.Manager.Email FROM MyCustomEntity
```

For future reference, the [User documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_user.htm)

Answer (score 4):

Determining the correct nomenclature for a relationship can be tricky depending on the object and relationship type.  I find it easiest to create the API WSDL and look at the object fields.  In the case of Manager field, the WSDL shows:

```
<element name="Manager" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="ens:User"/>
```

For comparison, a custom object relationship looks something like this:

```
<element name="Company_Users__r" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="tns:QueryResult"/>
```

Notice the __r in the later case.

(To create the WSDL, search for API in the setup menu and select Generate Enterprise WSDL.)

Comment: This isn't a bad idea, but for a Standard object like this it is usually much easier to just Google search the API documentation. They have this all already done in an easily readible format - http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_user.htm